# Vue Native - Debugging

Tags: react-native, vue-native

Recently I switched from Ionic framework to vue-native (vue.js wrapper around react-native), everything seems to be cool, development is fast and easy, but I have some real issues with debugging those apps. With Ionic Framework (Cordova) I was able to open an app in web browser and could easily manage Vuex state (for example) from Chrome Console. It doesn't seems so easy and trivial in react native world. Is it possible to have similar debugging experience in vue-native? When my app starts to grow and gets complicated it's really hard to handle it other way around. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is there any solution for debugging problem? any workaround specially webstorm...

Comment: @AhuraMazda please see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically all my problems gone away when I ported my apps to Expo (which allows for JS remote debugging) and grabbed `React Native Debugger` - https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger.

Important part is having simulator installed on your developer machine (like iphone simulator) because debugger doesn't play nicely with real machines.

Inside debugger hit cmd+t to open a new window and set port to 19001 (because of Expo using this port). Now start expo with `npm start` command and in Expo panel hit 'Run in simulator' button.

In simulator make a shake gesture (ctrl+cmd+z) and allow remote debugging in developer menu.

Done. Pleasant experience similar to one known from Cordova. You have a js console, you can inspect elements and change styles live. Expo comes with live reload to make things smoother.

More info here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/debugging/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot debug script parts in the VUE files in Chrome Dev Tools (you can put the breakpoints, but they are not working well), but if you put the methods to a separate JS file, it works like a charm. I know, it's a workaround, but not a big pain, and working well.

See my TODO app for example: https://github.com/TheBojda/VueNativeTodo